# Issue with embed async-await Discord.js - Error cannot read properties Discord.js

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

I have a problem with the code of a slash command from my Discord Bot.
I'm using Mongoose for DDB management, everything works fine, I removed most of the console.log() from the code to make it more readable here, but I retrieve all values ​​fine with no problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wd6C.png)

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const tiny = require("tiny-json-http");
const date = require('date-and-time');

const Calls = require('../calls.js');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://****:******@******.ilnqf.mongodb.net/******?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

/* ******************************** */
/* START DEFINING VARIOUS FUNCTIONS */
function priice(price) {
    return Number.parseFloat(price).toFixed(4);
}
function rentaa(renta) {
    return Number.parseFloat(renta).toFixed(2);
}
function roii(roi) {
    return Number.parseFloat(roi).toFixed(2);
}
/* END DEFINING VARIOUS FUNCTIONS */
/* ****************************** */

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('stats')
        .setDescription('CHECK YOUR STATS'),
    async execute(interaction) {

        let doc = await Calls.find({ userID: interaction.user.id })
        .then((doc) => { console.log("Result Find :", doc); })
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });

        Calls.aggregate([{ $match: { username: interaction.user.username } }, { $group: { _id: { username: interaction.user.username }, rent: { $sum: { $add: ["$roi"] } }, nbrcalls: { $sum: 1 } } }])
            .then((doc) => { console.log('AGGREGATE NBR CALLS: ' + doc[0]['nbrcalls'] + '\nAGGREGATE RENT: ' + doc[0]['rent']);
            Calls.countDocuments({ username: interaction.user.username, win: "1" })
            .then((count) => { console.log('WINS: ' + count);
                Calls.countDocuments({ username: interaction.user.username, loss: "1" })
                .then((count1) => { console.log('LOSSES: ' + count1);
                    let roi = (count / (count + count1)) * 100;
                    console.log('ROI: ' + roi);
                    let renta = doc[0]['rent'] / (count + count1);
                    console.log('RENTA: ' + renta);
                })
                .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
            })
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
        
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setDescription('<@' + interaction.user.id + '>, has a total of __' + doc[0]['nbrcalls'] + ' trades__.')
            .setColor(0x18e1ee)
            .setTimestamp(Date.now())
            .addFields(
                { name: "**WINS**", value: count + " ", inline: true },
                { name: "**LOSSES**", value: count1 + " ", inline: true },
                { name: "**WINRATE**", value: parseFloat(roii(roi)) + "%", inline: true },
                { name: "**AVERAGE ROI**", value: parseFloat(rentaa(renta)) + "%", inline: false }
            );
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
        console.log(embed);
    },
};
```

This is the error that I get

`Error executing stats TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at Object.execute (/Users/jeremy/commands/stats.js:50:86)`

If I understand correctly it is that my embed does not have access to the variables above. However, I can't see how to manage the embed because if I mount it the await.interaction does not work. Do you have a lead for me please?

I attach a screen shot of the same code with the console.log()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAFHu.png)

I know why it doesn't work but I don't see how to fix the problem, it's very annoying :D

I have tried to move around the embed const but it will not work if I move it up.

Comment: Can you share your code instead of using an image? It will be easier for us to help you and write a solution

Comment: Code added to the post ;)